# Spy on values in IE dynamically

Tags: blueprism, rpa

This is my collection of values that i read from the webpage using get table action.

I need to click on the webpage based on these values.
The values will change as well as the number of values.

How do i spy it such as the it will read ABC and go to the webpage and spy the values with ABC.

I am using Internet Explorer.

```
| Values|  
----------
| ABC   |  
| CDE   |  
| ACD   |
```

Comment: "spy the values with ABC"? Are there multiple elements with that value on the webpage? Are you sure about that? Because BP can only spy 1 element at a time. If it was a typo, then you should be able to pass a parameter of the element as dynamic and insert the value part in the action you are using to interact with the element.

Comment: Hi, may i know how to pass a parameter of the element as dynamic? I'm not too sure what you mean because i'm quite new to BP.

Comment: You should read the guides available on the BP website. Using dynamic parameters of an element is a basic knowledge, and it will be rather moot to explain the same thing here, plus you are sure to getcthe most updated guides there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you spy the element on the page you should have three Blue Prism Application Model 'matches' checked:

`ID` - `Equals` - {ID of Element}
`Class` - `Equals` - {Class pf Element}
`Value` - `Dynamic` - {Empty}

Then when you grab your table data and put it in a Collection you can dynamically pass in the specific 'Value' to the `Action` you're calling the Application Model element in.